# Jest test fail: "Window is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) application I have configure [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)) and [Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) for snapshot testing.

One of my tests failed with an error:

```
ReferenceError {
   message: 'window is not defined',
}
```

I'm using *window* (a global object) in a function and calling that function from a test file which contains a *window* object and that’s producing an error.

How can I resolve this? I tried

```
"globals":{
   "window":true
}
```

in my package JSON file, but I am still having this issue.
My test script is also running `jsdom`.

Comment: Do other keywords from `jsdom` work? Does accessing for example `document` throw any errors or is it just `window`?

Comment: How is your test script looks like? Have you tried this "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom" ????

Comment: @Reynicke No jsdom does not work I also got "document is not defined" error

Comment: @Think-Twice these are my test scripts in package json and I run test via "yarn run test"




`"scripts":{
"testendpoints": "env-cmd ./.env.test.local ava -v",
"testall": "yarn testendpoints && yarn testdom",
"test": "REACT_APP_ENV=development yarn testall",
}`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like JSDOM is not properly installed or somehow disabled. See if you can find something like this in your configuration:

`"testEnvironment": "node"`

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string

Comment: This solved my issue. I've forgotten that added `jest.config.js` and `"testEnvironment": "node"` in it